# Newbie PHP MySQL Question

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi I'm new to php mysql development. I'm using wamp server on windows. php5.3.4, mysql5.1, apache2.2. I try to execute this code but all I get is the error.php page. Is there a special way to insert in mysql if the table has auto_increment ids? In the code I give the NULL value for id.

Please help and please excuse my noob question!

```
function addMember($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $bday, $gender, $maritalStatus, $education, $occupation) {
    $personalQ = "INSERT INTO users_personal_profile VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    if($stmt3 = $this->conn->prepare($personalQ)) {
        $stmt3->bind_param('sssssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $bday, $gender, $education, $occupation, $maritalStatus);
        $stmt3->execute();
        if($stmt3->fetch()) {
            $stmt3->close();
            header("location: intermediate.php");
        }
        else {
            $stmt3->close();
            header("location: error.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `mysql_error()` and check for the error message .. looks like ur using some kind of framework

Comment: [`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) is normally for select queries, you're having an index query. Only use functions that make sense in the context. Better check what `execute` returns instead.

Comment: What should `fetch` return on `INSERT`? I think MySQL doesn't support `RETURNING` from `INSERT` so when you test `if($stmt3->fetch())` it always evaluates to false? (as hakre said)

Comment: thanks for the swift responses guys.. even before that, the $stmt3->execute(); statement itself doesn't execute. I don't see no values stored in the database.. what could be the problem? When I run a select statement on the table, it gives proper results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condensing the comments:

To see what's happening you could adapt your script:

```
function addMember($firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $bday, $gender, $maritalStatus, $education, $occupation) {
   $personalQ = "INSERT INTO users_personal_profile VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
   if($stmt3 = $this->conn->prepare($personalQ)) {
        $stmt3->bind_param('sssssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $bday, $gender, $education, $occupation, $maritalStatus);

        if( $stmt3->execute() ){
            $stmt3->close();
            header("location: intermediate.php");
        }
        else {
            echo $stmt3->error;
            //    header("location: error.php"); // can't output headers after outputting something, but it's just for debugging
        }
    }
}
```

That should get you some insight in if there is an actual error and what it says.

The autoincrement-field should be set in your db scheme. How is your table defined? Is the first field actually marked as autoincrement? (If it is, null should work.)
You can also execute the query directly into the database and see how it does. (You could use phpmyadmin or navicat or sql from the console for that.)

If you need the autoincrement value in the code, you can access it with `$mysqli_stmt->insert_id;`

Comment: That's it it worked! Removing the fetch statement totally worked! Thanksa lot Inca.. You are my savior..